# SQL Server Bulk Import With Format File of UTF-8 Data

Tags: sql-server, unicode, import, bulk

I have been referring to the following page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

I simply want to bulk import some data from a file that has Unicode characters. I have tried encoding the actual data file in UC-2, UTF-8, etc but nothing works. I have also modified the format file to use `SQLNCHAR`, but still it doesn't work and gives error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1

I think it has to do with this statement from the above link:

> *For a format file to work with a Unicode character data file, all the
>   input fields must be Unicode text strings (that is, either fixed-size
>   or character-terminated Unicode strings).*

What exactly does this mean? I thought this means every character string needs to be a fixed 2 bytes, which encoding the file in UCS-2 should handle???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This blog post was really helpful and solved my problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joaol/archive/2008/11/27/bulk-insert-using-unicode-data-files.aspx

Something else to note - a Java class was generating the data file. In order for the above solution to work, the data file needed to be encoded in **UTF-16LE**, which can be set in the constructor of OutputStreamWriter (for example).

Comment: The specific changes necessary, which that blog post clarified for me, are (in your format file): use `SQLNCHAR` rather than `SQLCHAR`; use '\t\0' for your field terminator (if you're using tabs); use '\r\0\n\0' for your row terminator (if you're using Windows line breaks).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 I imported a .csv file saved with Notepad++ enconded in UCS-2 with special spanish characters