# Fixed length Bulk Import with BCP format file

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have a huge fixed length flat file with no column delimiters, I am trying to port this data into a table using BCP utility.

Below is my sample format I created with BCP :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharFixed"   LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharFixed"  LENGTH="9"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharFixed"   LENGTH="20"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="NCharFixed"   LENGTH="4"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="NCharFixed"  LENGTH="15"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="NCharFixed"   LENGTH="15"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NCharFixed"   LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="NCharFixed"  LENGTH="8"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="NCharFixed"  LENGTH="8"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" LENGTH="19"/>

 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="BACD"  xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="SSN" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="LASTNAME" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="suffix" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="firstname" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="middlename" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="code" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="dod" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="dob" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="blank" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />

 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

My table design:
BACD nchar(1), SSN nchar(9), Lastname nchar(20), suffix nchar(4), firstname nchar(15), middlename nchar(15), code nchar(1), dod nchar(8), dob nchar(8), blank nchar(19)

Sample data:
 005070002Foobar                  FOOOO                          1100577505671903

SQL query:

```
BULK INSERT sample.dbo.DD FROM 'C:\sample-for-test.txt'
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\format-n.xml', ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n');
SELECT * FROM sample.dbo.DD;
```

Error I am getting is :
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (BACD).
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I checked the BACD column, the length is 1 character and the value in this case a space. All the columns allow nulls. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong? and why am i getting this error?

Comment: Take sample.dbo.DD out of the equation by testing with `SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\sample-for-test.txt', FORMATFILE 'C:\format-n.xml') t`

Comment: Hi @anon , Its the same error with that query.

Comment: Try with FIRSTROW = 2 to see if it is just the first line. Also, try with different options for CODEPAGE. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438569/sql-server-bulk-import-with-format-file-of-utf-8-data

Comment: @anon thanks to you I at least getting somewhere. I change my query to :

SELECT top 10 * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\sample-for-test.txt', 
FORMATFILE = 'C:\format-n.xml', FIRSTROW = 2, LASTROW=20) t;             Now I am getting the following error "The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 13. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly."

Comment: @anon update i tried \n as row terminator and now i am back to getting the "Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 1 (BACD)."  for the same select query

Comment: Well it worked ... changed NCharFixed to CharFixed..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at SQL Server stuff in years but my knee-jerk answer is that you need to define a primary key in the destination table. If you have one, maybe non-unique items in your BACD column are violating an existing index rule.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well it worked ... changed NCharFixed to CharFixed